# All Combinations of sub-strings in a sentence in java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I need to find the combinations of words in a space separated string . Suppose the String is "I will go" then the output will be -

1. I, will, go
2. I, will go
3. I will, go

String may be bigger. 
I tried but stuck. Would you please help me to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class Combination_Of_Words_In_Sentence {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputString = "I will go";
    String[] arrString = inputString.split(" ");
    printString(arrString);
}

private static void printString(String[] arrString) {
    int len = arrString.length;
    String[] arr = new String[len];

    for(int i=0;i<arrString.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<i+1;j++){
            arr[i] = arrString[j]+" ";
            System.out.println();
        }
        arr[i] +=",";
        printPatternUtil(arrString, arr, 1, 1, len);
    }   
}

private static void printPatternUtil(String[] arrString, String[] arr,
        int i, int j, int n) {
    if(i == n){
        // arr[j] = " ";
         for(int k=0;k<arr.length;k++)
         System.out.print(arr[k]);

         System.out.println();
            return;
    }
    arr[j] = arrString[i]+",";
    printPatternUtil(arrString, arr, i+1, j+1, n) ;

    // Or put a space followed by next character
   // arr[j] = ",";
    //arr[j+1] = arrString[i]+ " ";

   // printPatternUtil(arrString, arr, i+1, j+2, n);

}

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. you have to put commas in different positions ?

Comment: Hi Luca, Thanks for replying. I need list of String. List1 -> [I,will,go], List2 -> [I, will go] List3 -> [I will,go]

Comment: Yes.. That will also fine.

Comment: Please see here: [3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I would break up the sentence into individual words first. Then write some recursive solution. I haven’t worked out the details in my head, and they would be too much for the Stack Overflow format.

Comment: Hi Ole, I was trying like that way but stuck in recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that you use a bitwise solution, to avoid needing recursion.
You can count, in binary, the number of combinations you need.
For example, with two words, you need one comma.
With three words, you need two commas.
So, number of commas = number of words - 1.

We can represent the commas with bits in a counter.

- First comma = bit 0
- Second comma = bit 1
- Third comma = bit 2
- etc...

So, for two commas, we need 2 bits.
The possible combinations with 2 bits is:

- 0b00 = 0
- 0b01 = 1
- 0b10 = 2
- 0b11 = 3

For three commas, the possible combinations are 0b000 = 0, 0b001 = 1, 0b010 = 2, 0b011 = 3, 0b100 = 4, 0b101 = 5, 0b110 = 6, and 0b111 = 7

So, for two commas, you just need to count from 0 (0b00) to 3 (0b11) and test each bit to see if you need to insert a comma.  For three commas, count from 0 (0b000) to 7 (0b111).

This is easy to calculate.  For 2 commas, take 2 to the power 2 = 4. For 3 commas, take 2 to the power 3 = 8.

```
String[] words = {...};
int wordcount = words.length;
int commacount = wordcount - 1;
// Calculate the highest number to count to, in our loop
int looplimit = 1 << commacount; // Same as 2 to the power commacount;
for(int i=0;i<looplimit;i++)
{
    // Start this phrase version with the first word.
    String result = words[0];

    // Add the rest of the words, optionally adding commas.
    // We've already added a word, so only count to wordcount-1
    for(int j = 0; j<wordcount-1;j++)
    {
        // For word j, test the loop counter (i) to see if bit j is set.
        boolean needComma = (i & (1 << j)) != 0;

        // Add a comma or a space to this phrase version
        result += needComma ? "," : " ";

        // Add this word to the phrase version
        result += words[j+1];
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```